# How to generate xsd file cxf-java2ws-plugin

Tags: maven

I have written the webservices and through the maven I am succesfully generating the wsdl but how I'll generate the xsd ?

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <className>com.TestWebServices</className>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How to generate the xsd with maven?

Answer (score 4):

By default the schema is generated in the wsdl file. If what you want is to have the xsd in a separate file, modify your pom by adding:

```
<argline>-createxsdimports</argline>
```

In the java2ws-plugin configuration (in your case, it would go alongside the `<verbose>` tag).